# Windows 10 Auto Shut Down

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am doing a production at my school tonight, and we have a massive issue. The laptop which controls the lighting system has an automatic shut down time at 9.00. The show runs until almost 10.00 and when the laptop shuts down, as you can imagine, so do the lights. This is something which happens to all the PC's in the school. I'm pretty sure we have admin rights on the laptop itself, I just don't know how to disable this. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t know how the auto shutdown is implemented and I guess it needs to be working again the next day.

So the easiest method i can think of would be to **set the laptops time to like 8 in the morning** when you start setting up your presentation. This gives you a 13 hour time window before the auto shutdown kicks in. After your presentation just reset the time to the correct time.

If the Laptop has an Internet connection during the presentation maybe also disable automatic time setting (NTP) or it might update itself during the presentation and shut down anywas.